# Subscribe to observable is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

So I am trying to subscribe to a simple service that return data from a local JSON file.

I have managed to get the service working, I can log it out in the function, but when I subscribe to the service in the angular 2 component, it is always undefined. I'm not sure why? Any help would be much appreciated.

API service

```
export class ApiService {
   public data: any;

   constructor(private _http: Http) {
   }

   getData(): any {
       return this._http.get('api.json').map((response: Response) => { 
       console.log('in response', response.json()); //This logs the Object
       this.data = response.json();
       return this.data;
   })
   .catch(this.handleError);
   }
}
```

Component

```
export class AppComponent {
   public data: any
   public informationData;

   constructor(private _api: ApiService) {}

   public ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.getDataFromService()); // This return undefined
   }

   public getDataFromService() {
      this._api.getData().subscribe(response => {
          this.informationData = response;
          return this.informationData;
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: `getDataFromService` doesn't itself return anything. Change `.subscribe` to `.map` and return the resulting observable, then use `| async` to resolve it in the template.

Comment: A subscribe function doesnt return the data. It returns a `Subscription` object. i.e if you return the function call itself.

Comment: @SurajRao Yes, I noticed this, how do I get it to return the response data?

Comment: _where do you want to return it to_?

Comment: you can save it in class variable within subscribe if that is what you want

Comment: @SurajRao is that not what I have done already in the subscribe with `this.informationData = response;`, `return this.informationData;`?

Comment: why `return this.informationData;` its why I asked why you need to return from subscribe?

Comment: So just remove `return this.informationData;` as it is already been assigned to the variable? Thank you for all this

Answer (score 68):

Maybe some pictures help?

The numbers here indicate the order of operations.

**Send the Http Request**
[image]

1. Component is initialized and calls the getMovies method of the movieService.
2. The movieService getMovies method returns an Observable. NOT the data at this point.
3. The component calls `subscribe` on the returned Observable.
4. The `get` request is submitted to the server for processing.
5. The `ngOnInit` method is complete.

Any code here after the `subscribe` cannot access the `movies` property since the data has not yet been returned.

**Receive the Http Response**
[image]

At some LATER point in time ...

6. The movies are returned to the service.
7. If the process was successful, the first callback function is executed.
8. The local movies property is assigned to the movies returned from the service. It is only here that the movies property is finally set.

Attempting to access the movies property prior to step #8 results in an error.

**Can we access the value here? NO**
[image]

**To fix it:**
[image]

Comment: After few days of searching answer I found your post. Thank your very much Deborah! That's what I am looking for. But could you tell me how to parse/manipulate data from this.movies? I need to collect this and show in chart using chart.js/ ng chart

Comment: This was spectacularly well written and demonstrated. Thank you @DeborahK!

Comment: This did not seem to do the trick. Calling this.movies.length, still did not populate my html: <li *ngFor="let m of movies">{{m.name}}</li> results in a list of <li _ngcontent-c4></li> with no names. even adding {{m.name|async}} did not do the trick.

Comment: That was not the point of this example. Calling `this.movies.length` will not cause the list to populate. Calling the `.subscribe` and setting `this.movies = movies` causes the `this.movies` to populate. This post was trying to show why you can't get the length outside of the observable. Try posting a new question and showing some of your code. Tag me and I'll take a look.

Comment: What a fantastic explanation! Anyone struggling with asynch should take a look at this reply.

Comment: To prove DeborahK's point you can add delay just below the `this.movieService.getMovies().subscribe(.....);`

`await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 1000));`
And now check the length or content.

Answer (score 0):

```
objResponse;
this.service.getData().subscribe((result: any)=> { 
this.objResponse=result;
}
```

Returning something won't required

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

In your app-component:

```
public getDataFromService() {
  this._api.getData(this);
}


public setData(data: any){
 this.data=data;
}
```

In your service/api.ts:

```
public getData(obj: appComponentModel){
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(res => obj.setData(res));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
getData(): any {
       return this._http.get('api.json');
}
```

or

```
   getData(): any {
           return this._http.get('api.json').map((response: Response) => { 
    response.json();
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You've got a problem between sync and async function. You'r issue is: `getDateFromService` is syncronous and the content inside is async. So when the `ngOnInit` function call `getDataFromService`, you'r code don't wait the async task. you'r `getDataFromService` need to return an observer or need to implement the return of your API (you need to choose).

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.getDataFromService().subscribe(data => console.log(data)); // This return undefined
}

public getDataFromService() {
  return this._api.getData();
}
```

Comment: This works well, however when I try and add the `data` to a class variable it then still return undefined

Comment: Where do you want to get the response of your api? Because your problem here is you use sync/async functions. If in your class you have `undefined`, it's probably that your class don't wait the async call response before doing a `console.log`

Answer (score -1):

> Instead of logging at the ngOnInit() method as you did

```
 public ngOnInit(): void {
      console.log(this.getDataFromService()); // This return undefined    }
```

> log inside the subscribe() method as

```
export class AppComponent {
  public data: any
  public informationData;

  constructor(private _api: ApiService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDataFromService(); //don't log here, logging here will return undefined
  }

  public getDataFromService() {
    this._api.getData().subscribe(response => {
      this.informationData = response;
      console.log(this.informationData); //log here, like this
      return this.informationData;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Imagine 'subscribe' as a separate thread running, write everything that is needed inside an anonymous function inside 'subscribe'. Whenever the 'data' is available, it will be available inside the subscribe method.

Hope this helps.