# How to use the data sent by a provider only when available?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a provider that reads the data from a JSON and I want it to send the data to a page.
To ensure that the data is well sent to the UI I have a console.log that is supposed to show the first element of the array, but the issue is that I don't know how to only call this console.log once the information has been retrieved and passed by the provider.
the intention of course is not the console.log, but to do actual things with the data, once it's passed by the provider.

The provider :

```
getWorldCities(){
    if (this.worldCities) {
  // already loaded data
  return Promise.resolve(this.worldCities);
}
    this.http.get('../assets/city.list.json')
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.headers);
        this.worldCities = data;
        return Promise.resolve(this.worldCities);
      },
      err => console.log(err),
      () => console.log('yay')
    )
  }

}
```

And in my page :

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ChooseCity');
    console.log(this.worldCities);
    this.AppCitiesProvider.getWorldCities().then(data => {
      this.worldCities = data;
      console.log(this.worldCities[0]);
    });
  }
```

the error I get is :

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

How should I do that properly ?

Answer (score 1):

The "best practice" for retrieving data and performing operations once the data is received is to use the Observable instead of a promise. Something like this:

**In the service:**

```
getMovies(): Observable<IMovie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(this.moviesUrl)
        .do(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

handleError(error) {
  // Your error handling here.
  console.error(error);
}
```

**In the component:**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.movieService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(
            (movies: IMovie[]) => { 
                this.movies = movies;
                this.filteredMovies = this.performFilter(this.listFilter);
            },
            (error: any) => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}
```

Any code within the first callback function to the subscribe will only be executed after the data is retrieved.

See this for more information (and pictures!) [Subscribe to observable is returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769042/subscribe-to-observable-is-returning-undefined/46782678#46782678)

Comment: Thanks, I have a question though. what is this.handleError ? it generates issues in my code and I don't know how to fix it. Also why do you have this.http.get<Whatever[]> ? and not simply http.get ? Thank you so much

Comment: I'm using the new HttpClient that is part of Angular 4.3. If you are using an older version of Angular then you need the older syntax without the generic parameter `<Whatever[]>`. And the `handleError` is just a method that handles any errors you have.