# HttpClientModule return empty Array

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanna use HttpClientModule to get access Post's Array.
I'm just learning Angular, so could anyone explain to me why this is wrong

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HatedPostListComponent } from './hated-post-list/hated-post-list.component';
import { HatedAboutUsComponent } from './hated-about-us/hated-about-us.component';
import { HatedLoginComponent } from './hated-login/hated-login.component';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HatedPostListComponent,
    HatedAboutUsComponent,
    HatedLoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [DataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './services/data.service';
import { Post } from './models/user.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Frontend';
  constructor (private _svc: DataService) {
    console.log('Data in component' + this._svc.data);
  }
  getDate(): Array<Post> {
    return this._svc.data;
  }
}
```

> data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from '../models/user.model';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  baseURL: string;
  data: Array<Post> = [];
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseURL = 'http://localhost:5000/Posts?from=0&number=10';

  }
  getDate() {
    this._http.get<Array<Post>>(this.baseURL)
    .subscribe(response => {
      this.data = response;
      console.log('Subcribed data:' + this.data);
      console.log('Subcribed response:' + response);
    }
  );
  console.log('Data after subcribe:' + this.data);
  }
}
```

This is what I it 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lojV.png)
When I subcribe() everything is Ok, but after that My data is empty

Comment: Just move `data: Array<Post> = [];` and the `.subscribe(response => { //...` too the component rather than the service. Don't subscribe in the service, subscribe in the component.

Comment: The http request is happening asynchronously. Your console log (`console.log('Data after subcribe:' + this.data);`) is happening outside of the asynchronous code, and thus is why you are seeing that logged to the console before the other logs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subscribe to observable is returning undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769042/subscribe-to-observable-is-returning-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your implementation to following you would get the expected result.

Your Component :

```
getDate(){
  this._svc.getDate().subscribe((res)=> {
    console.log(res)
  });
}
```

Your Service :

```
getDate() {
  return this._http.get(this.baseURL);
}
```

This should work. The issue with your logic is you are just listening to current value of the data from service. where that point of time service holds [], after receiving data from API your component is not notified the change, unless you subscribe to it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call the service and subscribe in your component not in the service .

Change your service code as,

```
getDate() {
   return this._http.get<Array<Post>>(this.baseURL);
}
```

and in your component,

```
 getDate(): Array<Post> {
    this._svc.getDate().subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);       
      },
      err => console.log(err)
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? `.pipe(map(res => res))` That doesn't seem to be needed.

Comment: Probably because your initial answer was just "You need to call the service and subscribe in your component not in the service ."

Comment: haha i get that, but everyone needs sometime to update the full answer :)